# Ubuntu18 server combining snap install of rocketchat and nextcloud

Tags: server, apache2, proxy, snap, nginx

I installed a fresh Ubuntu18 server with Nextcloud and Rocketchat installed through snap.

After enabling letsencrypt, Nextcloud listens on port 443 and Rocketchat on port 3000.

I would like both to listen on port 443 based on domain names without having to deal with their certificates. (https://rocketchat.example.com:443 and https://nextcloud.example.com:443).

When I searched, it appears that I should install apache or nginx and do a proxy server. But everything was dealing directly with the certificates, which I would like to avoid. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872482/error-during-ssl-handshake-with-remote-server) gave me the hint on how to do and I came to the following config file for an apache reverse proxy:

**nextcloud.conf:**

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName nextcloud.example.com

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyVerify none
        SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
        SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

        SSLCertificateFile /var/snap/nextcloud/current/certs/live/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/snap/nextcloud/current/certs/live/privkey.pem

        Proxypass / https://localhost:44300/
        ProxypassReverse / https://localhost:44300/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**rocketchat.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName rocketchat.example.com

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.ljp.upmc.fr/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.ljp.upmc.fr/privkey.pem

        <Location />
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:3000/$1 [P,L]

        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you. I had problems with caddy and port 445 so I went your way.